# Bootstrap 3 confirm delete row on table not work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner. my confirm delete dialog not work when click save change button on modal nothing happened some one please help me

My table

```
+-------+----------------+---------------+
| carid |     carname    | edit | delete |
+-------+----------------+---------------+
|   1   | bugatti veyron | edit | delete |
+-------+----------------+---------------+
```

delete button on table

```
<a href="lib/delete.php?carid=<?php echo $item["carid"];?>" type="button" 
   class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete">
   Delete
</a>
```

modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete confirm</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <p>Are you sure</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class=" btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="btn-delete">
                        Save change
                    </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");

$gtid = $_GET["carid"];
//echo $gtid;

$sql=("DELETE FROM car WHERE carid='$gtid'") or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

header("Location:../car.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your delete button actually knows what to do when you click it. It's just a button, it doesn't have any attributes or functions (as far as I can see) that does anything.

When the user first clicks on the delete-button in your table you need to copy that URL and add it to the "Save changes"-button (which in that case needs to be a link).

Bootstrap has a great example on just this type of thing right here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Hopefully this will get you on the right track!